# Cannot get Sql Server Business Intelligence Development Studio Tools and templates to show up in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, business-intelligence, ssis-2012

I have tried every suggested method for installing Business Intelligence for SQl Server 2012 (ssdtbi) AND for Visual Studio 2012 with service packs installed (ssdt) and cannot get Business Intelligence Development Studio Tools or Templates to show up in either application. I have uninstalled VS 2013, I have uninstalled VS 2012 and reinstalled VS 2012 with service packs, and each time after removing any SSDTBI and SSDT via the control panel and then installing the March 2013 versions, I still cannot get the templates to show. 
What have I missed? Where can I look now for clues? No error messages are showing up, just no templates in VS and when you click on SQL SERVER Data Tools for Visual Studio under Sql Server 2012, of course you get VS 2012 firing up and no templates. 
We are running x64 machines, with Windows 7 currently. Please someone give me hope. thanks.

Comment: Well, there was no SSDT-BI for VS2012 version released this March. You're saying that installing SSDT-BI for VS2012 from http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=36843 doesn't install the templates?

Answer (score 0):

Business Intelligence tools for VS 2013 were pulled temporarily due to an issue. It was reposted recently and is currently only available in English at the following location.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Microsoft Connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/806079/ssdt-bi-add-visual-studio-2013-support-to-sql-server-data-tools-for-business-intelligence

Since the issue was related to side by side installations of 2013 and 2012, there may be undeleted files remaining on your system that are causing issues or you may not be using the latest version released by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of trouble getting SSDT-BI to install properly.  A few hints follow:

1. If possible, start with a clean OS.  If not possible, uninstall everything that you can find related to Visual Studio.
2. Use the correct version of Visual Studio for your target version of SSIS.  Since you mention SSIS 2012, you should use Visual Studio 2012 (not 2013).  See this [entry from Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2014/04/03/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi.aspx) for a bit of background.  The version of SSDT-BI that you need is here:
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843
3. If you need normal SSDT, install version of SSDT for the SSIS version you're using.

The last thing to keep in mind is that it can be difficult to get the SSIS toolbox and SSIS menu to appear.  The easiest way that I have found is to start a Business Intelligence - Integration Services project and then look for the SSIS menu in the same line as the File Menu.  Once there you should find the SSIS Toolbox as an option to display.

Good Luck!